# Show first table value only php

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I need to give echo the first table value, exemple:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("Select * FROM Table_tb");
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchAll();
```

The code below shows me all values of the name column:

```
<?= $row["NAME"] ?>
```

Let's assume that the column has 2 names,

```
ID  NAME    SIZE 
0   NAME1   100
1   NAME2   100
```

how can I give echo or print_r and only show NAME1 instead of all.

Comment: "_The code below shows me all values of the name column:_" No, it doesn't. `$row` isn't even defined in the code you are showing us. Also, your description of what you want to do seems a bit lacking in detail, it's hard to tell what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: What is the logic - show only first or all except first?

Comment: @ please describe more what you want?

Comment: I want instead of showing all values of the name column, show only 1 specific value!

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch the first row only from the returned results instead of all, try the below code:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table_tb");
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetch();
echo $data['NAME'];
```

Comment: With this code how can I also see only the NAME2 value?